# Vaex: AttributeError: module 'vaex' has no attribute 'from_pandas'

Tags: python, pandas, vaex

I'm facing a following error when run the script in a Linux environment.
I appreciate anyone who could help to fix this issue.

**Vaex: AttributeError: module 'vaex' has no attribute 'from_pandas' on following environment.**

I haven't encountered same error and tested successfully with both windows and Mac laptops, but I'm getting this error in a following Red Hat Linux environment.

- RHEL version 7.9
- Python version 3.9(anaconda3.9)
- Vaex version 4.9.2

actual code is below.

```
self.vdf_data = vaex.from_pandas(df=self.df_data, copy_index=False)
```

print(vaex)

<module 'vaex' (namespace)>

print(dir(vaex))

['**doc**', '**file**', '**loader**', '**name**', '**package**', '**path**', '**spec**']

Comment: What's your (*.py*) script name? (Is it *vaex.py*)?

Comment: hi, CristiFati, thank you for your support, my script name is td_report.py

Comment: `print(vaex)`, `print(dir(vaex))` (before the faulty line).

Comment: hi, CristiFati, i have added screenshots for above two commands. would you please take a look at?

Comment: Don't add images, but copy/paste (and format) the text. And in the 1st image the thing that matters the most (file path) is missing.

Comment: print(vaex)

<module 'vaex' (namespace)>

print(dir(vaex))

['__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__']

Comment: CristiFati i have removed the pictures. i see now. in the environment where the script works i can see the result is very different.

Comment: looks like an installation issue to me. Can you do anything else with vaex? Like run `df = vaex.example()` in the same environment / script? Just to see if things work.

Comment: Joco, yes, there was missing library dependencies, after i installed them it worked